# Importing file returns Error 3134 - Syntax Error

Tags: vba, ms-access, syntax-error

This code was written in 2017 and has worked since - it is giving me a syntax error.

Its a lengthy invoice file we import monthly - finds the correct quarter to append the temp table to.

```
    db.Execute "INSERT INTO" & varQuarter & " ([Ship Date], [Invoice Date], [Sell Price per Unit], 
   [Differential Amount]," _
 & " [Net Product Amount], [Amount Due], [Product Sell Amount Due], [Discount Amount Due], 
 [Miscellaneous Amount Due]," _
 & " [Storage Amount Due], [Overage Storage Amount Due], [Freight Amount Due], [Tax Amount Due], 
 [Memo Sell Amount]," _
 & " [Memo Tax Amount], [Billing Unit Quantity], [Billing Unit Count], [Billing Unit Code], [Shipped 
 Quantity]," _
& " [Invoiced Quantity], [Invoice Source System], [Invoice Number], [Invoice Bill Code], [Order 
Number], [Form Number]," _
& " [Form Name], [PO Number], [Requisition Number], [Billing Cost Center Number], [Using Cost Center 
Number]," _
& " [Warehouse Number], [Bill Of Lading Number], [Bill Of Lading Item Number], [Ship Mark For Text], 
[CCN Customer Name]," _
& " [CCN Customer Number], [Bill to Customer Name], [Bill to Customer Number], [Ship To Customer 
Number]," _
& " [Ship To Customer Name], [Ship To  Address Line1], [Ship To  Address Line2], [Ship To City], 
[Ship To State]," _
& " [Ship To Zip Code], [Plant Code], [Plant Name], [Product Code], [Product Name], [Postage Amount 
Due]," _
& " [Freight Carrier Code], [Category Title])" _
& " SELECT [Ship Date], [Invoice Date], [Sell Price per Unit], [Differential Amount], [Net Product 
Amount], [Amount Due]," _
& " [Product Sell Amount Due], [Discount Amount Due], [Miscellaneous Amount Due], [Storage Amount 
Due]," _
& " [Overage Storage Amount Due], [Freight Amount Due], [Tax Amount Due], [Memo Sell Amount], [Memo 
Tax Amount]," _
& " [Billing Unit Quantity], [Billing Unit Count], [Billing Unit Code], [Shipped Quantity], [Invoiced 
Quantity]," _
& " [Invoice Source System], [Invoice Number], [Invoice Bill Code], [Order Number], [Form Number], 
[Form Name], [PO Number]," _
& " [Requisition Number], [Billing Cost Center Number], [Using Cost Center Number], [Warehouse 
Number], [Bill Of Lading Number]," _
& " [Bill Of Lading Item Number], [Ship Mark For Text], [CCN Customer Name], [CCN Customer Number], 
[Bill to Customer Name]," _
& " [Bill to Customer Number], [Ship To Customer Number], [Ship To Customer Name], [Ship To  Address 
Line1]," _
& " [Ship To  Address Line2], [Ship To City], [Ship To State], [Ship To Zip Code], [Plant Code], 
[Plant Name], [Product Code]," _
 & " [Product Name], [Freight Carrier Code], [Postage Amount Due], [Category Title]" _
 & " FROM tblInvoicesTemp;"
```

Comment: Maybe something about data has changed. However, I do see that there is a missing space following `"INSERT INTO" & ` in which case I don't see how this could ever have worked. Why have a table for each quarter and not just 1 table with another field for quarter?

Comment: You should not maintain *many* similarly structured tables in a relational database. Use a **single** table with any indicator fields such as `quarter`. Additionally, avoid dynamic SQL strings in VBA. Instead use stored Access queries for efficiency, organization, readability, and maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply avoid VBA string queries requiring long concatenation, line breaks and quotes. Specifically, your issue appears to be the `INSERT INTO" & VarQuarter & "` which if the space is not the issue (i.e., StackOverflow post typo) it may be the actual value of `VarQuarter`. Should the table name maintain a space (like all your columns) or special character or leading number, it must be escaped either with square brackets or backticks.

However, avoid this long string building altogether by saving an Access stored query and preferably a ***single*** final invoice table. Doing so, you don't have to worry about line breaks or concatenation. Additionally, the Query Designer does not save SQL with syntax issues and the Access engine caches statistics for best execution plan on stored queries (hence why they run better than parsed SQL run on the fly in VBA). Should you need to pass VBA values in `WHERE` clauses, you can still use saved queries with parameters support.

**SQL** *(save as Access stored query or one for each quarter table)*

```sql
INSERT INTO [myFinalTable] ([Ship Date], [Invoice Date], [Sell Price per Unit], 
                            [Differential Amount], [Net Product Amount], [Amount Due], 
                            [Product Sell Amount Due], [Discount Amount Due], 
                            [Miscellaneous Amount Due], [Storage Amount Due], 
                            [Overage Storage Amount Due], [Freight Amount Due], 
                            [Tax Amount Due], [Memo Sell Amount], [Memo Tax Amount], 
                            [Billing Unit Quantity], [Billing Unit Count], [Billing Unit Code], 
                            [Shipped Quantity], [Invoiced Quantity], [Invoice Source System], 
                            [Invoice Number], [Invoice Bill Code], [Order Number], [Form Number],
                            [Form Name], [PO Number], [Requisition Number], [Billing Cost Center Number], 
                            [Using Cost Center Number], [Warehouse Number], [Bill Of Lading Number], 
                            [Bill Of Lading Item Number], [Ship Mark For Text], [CCN Customer Name],
                            [CCN Customer Number], [Bill to Customer Name], [Bill to Customer Number], 
                            [Ship To Customer Number], [Ship To Customer Name], [Ship To  Address Line1], 
                            [Ship To  Address Line2], [Ship To City], [Ship To State],
                            [Ship To Zip Code], [Plant Code], [Plant Name], [Product Code], [Product Name], 
                            [Postage Amount Due], [Freight Carrier Code], [Category Title])

SELECT [Ship Date], [Invoice Date], [Sell Price per Unit], [Differential Amount]
     , [Net Product Amount], [Amount Due], [Product Sell Amount Due], [Discount Amount Due]
     , [Miscellaneous Amount Due], [Storage Amount Due], [Overage Storage Amount Due]
     , [Freight Amount Due], [Tax Amount Due], [Memo Sell Amount], [Memo Tax Amount]
     , [Billing Unit Quantity], [Billing Unit Count], [Billing Unit Code], [Shipped Quantity]
     , [Invoiced Quantity], [Invoice Source System], [Invoice Number], [Invoice Bill Code]
     , [Order Number], [Form Number], [Form Name], [PO Number], [Requisition Number]
     , [Billing Cost Center Number], [Using Cost Center Number], [Warehouse Number] 
     , [Bill Of Lading Number], [Bill Of Lading Item Number], [Ship Mark For Text]
     , [CCN Customer Name], [CCN Customer Number], [Bill to Customer Name]
     , [Bill to Customer Number], [Ship To Customer Number], [Ship To Customer Name]
     , [Ship To  Address Line1], [Ship To  Address Line2], [Ship To City]
     , [Ship To State], [Ship To Zip Code], [Plant Code], [Plant Name], [Product Code]
     , [Product Name], [Freight Carrier Code], [Postage Amount Due], [Category Title]
 FROM tblInvoicesTemp;
```

**VBA**

```vb
DoCmd.OpenQuery "myAppendQuery"     ' NO NEED TO CLOSE ACTION QUERIES
```

Now if you use many quarter tables, save a corresponding query for each one and dynamically assign the query name and pass variable value in `OpenQuery` call:

```vb
Dim VarQuarter
VarQuarter = ...

DoCmd.OpenQuery VarQuarter        ' NO NEED TO CLOSE ACTION QUERIES
```

To avoid user update/insert warnings, use your earlier method of `Database.Execute`:

```vb
Dim VarQuarter
VarQuarter = ...

db.Execute VarQuarter
```

Comment: So - We upload the data to a temp table - where we run a query to attach the category. From there we append it the appropriate quarter. This is due to the amount of lines. Just to help clarify. This was all built by someone who has since retired.